# Violation of DAO pattern. What to do?

Tags: java, dao

I need to generate and then perform a complex sql-query which is going to access multiple databases to create some general `report`. This implies that the query's not related to a specific `DAO` object.

So where should I put the logic of executing such a query and returning result as `DTO`? If I create `ReportDao` interface and then implement it it may lead another developer into troubles, beucasu I think they will expect the `Dao` object tied with some table in the database.

Comment: Is it going to access multiple database in the same query? Or use the results from multiple databases?

Comment: @EvanKnowles Yes, it's going to be a `dblink` query.

Comment: There are many decisions on a project that 'may' lead 'some' developer into trouble.  Do a quick poll of the options with people in your team, and see how they feel.  A single DAO with multiple data sources is not pure evil, a composite DAO is also reasonable as is a service layer that aggregates multiple DAOs.

Comment: You can put it in the most important class DAO (in the case the rest of the data is derived of that class), or you can create a DAO just for Reports (and make clear to the team the purpose of this DAO)...

Comment: @ChrisK The issue is I don't need a composite DAO here. I need to execute the query because of the sorting.

Comment: @user3663882 please try explaining that again

Comment: @ChrisK Well, I need to sort the data getting from the query and I'd like to do it on the SQL-server side.

Comment: @user3663882 I fail to see where that came from in the question; perhaps you should revise the question to make it clearer.  From what you just said about wanting to sort in the SQL-server, that sounds like a run of the mill order by clause in a select statement.  But you already knew that right?  So what am I missing?

Comment: Why would accessing more than one table be a violation of the DAO pattern?

Comment: @Tobb So, how could I call that dao? ReportDao? But thereis no report table in the database.

Comment: From what I know, a DAO does not necessarily have to be linked to a specific domain class. No domain class lives in isolation, and if one presumes a DAO to only include operations on one table/domain class, one is in for a surprise, since operations might pertain to multiple domain classes, and thus be wrongly placed no matter where you put it. It's better to also think of a DAO as a collection of methods pertaining to a certain area of functionality. If most Dao are modeled around domain objects it might be wise to name the different one a bit differently, but ReportDao should be fine...

Comment: ... as long as we're talking about a collection of methods pertaining to reports/reporting. Or maybe "GeneralReportDataDao" is better (keep in mind that I only have the information in your question to work with, think about what the class represents and try to find a descriptive name..)

Comment: @Tobb Great point, why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!Opinion warning!

A DAO does not necessarily have to be linked to a specific domain class. No domain class lives in isolation, and if one presumes a DAO to only include operations on one table/domain class, one is in for a surprise, since operations might pertain to multiple domain classes, and thus be wrongly placed no matter where you put it. It's better to also think of a DAO as a collection of methods pertaining to a certain area of functionality. If most Dao are modeled around domain objects it might be wise to name the different one a bit differently, but ReportDao should be fine as long as we're talking about a collection of methods pertaining to reports/reporting. Or maybe "GeneralReportDataDao" is better (keep in mind that I only have the information in your question to work with, think about what the class represents and try to find a descriptive name..)

Another point I have seen from experience when organizing DAOs after domain classes, is that the DAOs pertaining to central domain classes tends to grow very large, since central domain classes are often linked to large amounts of functionality. This is not only true for DAO-classes, but also for Services, etc, using the same pattern for organizing functionality.

We mainly have two "types" of classes in Java, we have classes that *represent* something (classes containing data, typically stateful classes), and classes that *do* something (service, dao, etc, typically stateless classes). The stateful data classes should be named and modeled after what they represent, i.e. the data, while the stateless service classes should be named and modeled after functionality. While it is tempting to try to organize services the same way as data, it often leads to poor code, with large classes and areas of functionality spread across several classes.